# Laravel 5 - cannot install laracasts/generators

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am trying to install [Laravel 5 Extended Generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) through Composer, using the following command: `composer require laracasts/generators --dev`.

I received this error message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package way/generators dev-feature/laravel-5-stable could not be found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setti                        ng
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

The version of Laravel I am using is 5.2. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to this issue [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-migrations-from-existing-database?page=1#reply-102015). Basically, composer.json should look like this:

```
"require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "xethron/migrations-generator": "dev-l5",
        "way/generators": "dev-feature/laravel-five-stable"
    },
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/jamisonvalenta/Laravel-4-Generators.git"
        }
    ],
```